# WP query by custom post type slug/name

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

I am running a simple wp query to retrieve just one post.

But the post is a custom post-type post, not a normal post

```
$ajaxBike = $_GET['varbike']; 

$bikeProfile = new WP_Query(array(

    'name'          => $ajaxBike,
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'app_visibility',
            'value' => 1,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )

));
```

or...

```
$ajaxBike = $_GET['varbike']; 

$bikeProfile = new WP_Query('name='.$ajaxBike);
```

But I think the **name** parameter only works for posts. But I'm struggling to find anything to work with a custom post type slug.

Can you anyone help work out how to query a custom post type using the slug?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
'post_type' => 'custom post type slug'
```

By default 'post_type' is set as 'post', you will need to specify your custom post type in any query you make.

In future refer here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: This worked great thank you. Just added 'post_type' => 'on-road' and it pulled it in :-)